# Using fraction in case makes small letters

Tags: equations, align, fractions, cases

I have wrote the following in LaTeX:

```
\begin{align}
& \tan(\Gamma_{4}) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{x_{T3} - x_{T2}}{y_{T3} - y_{T2}} & \text{if} \qquad x_{T3}>x_{T2} \\ \\
\frac{x_{T2}-x_{T3}}{y_{T2}-y_{T3}} & \text{if} \qquad x_{T3} < x_{T2}
\end{cases} \\
& (T_{2})_{Calc}: ((x_{T2})_{Calc},(y_{T2})_{Calc}) = (x_{T3} - (y_{T3}-y_{L2}) \cdot \tan(\Gamma_{4}),y_{L2})
\end{align}
```

and I obtain the following results:

[image]

The thing is that the text inside the fraction becomes very small compared to the other equations.

Is there a way to make them have the same size as the rest?

Comment: worked, thank you very much

Comment: @campa I'm not fast, I'm not marmot! However, you have to hurry because egreg has already marked it as duplicate!